# Why is if is admin not working?

Tags: php, wordpress

I edited a bit of code the other day from the Wordpress Ultimate Members plug-in to change the user profile to pending if the profile is edited by the user.

However, I noted that the code also sets the admin account to pending too.  I don’t want this, so I have been trying to use an if/ else statement to query if the user is admin before the script runs.

I know this is straight forward for experts in PHP, but I have tried lots of variations and admin is still being set to pending approval.

Here’s the original code that is setting admin to pending:

```
// Set profile to under review after edits
add_action('um_user_edit_profile', 'um_post_edit_pending_hook', 10, 2); 
    function um_post_edit_pending_hook($user_id, $args){ 
        global $ultimatemember; 
        $ultimatemember->user->pending(); 
}
```

Here s the code that I am trying to bypass admin with which won’t work.  I won’t add all the variations I have tried.

```
add_action('um_user_edit_profile', 'um_post_edit_pending_hook', 10, 2); 
function um_post_edit_pending_hook($user_id, $args){ 
if ( is_admin() ) {
    return false;
    } else { 
        global $ultimatemember; 
        $ultimatemember->user->pending(); 
    }
}
```

Any assistance would gratefully be appreciated.

Comment: What does `is_admin()` do? What does the code inside that function?

Comment: @DiddleDot , it's a [core WordPress function](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_admin)

Comment: Have you checked if `is_admin()` returns the correct value?

Comment: You could use `if(current_user_can('administrator')){}else{}`. @user45250 has already answered this.

Comment: I'll try.  So the actual code is good then? I mean in the correct order with nothing missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This Conditional Tag checks if the Dashboard or the administration panel is attempting to be displayed. It should not be used as a means to verify whether the current user has permission to view the Dashboard or the administration panel (try `current_user_can()` instead):

https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/current_user_can

Source:

https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_admin

Comment: I will try. But it is being used to check if a user can edit their profile in the plugin, users are excluded from using the wp_admin dashboard elsewhere.

Answer (score 0):

> **@user45250** has explained this very well. I have added this answer to provide some example code.

Here is the code from my earlier comment.

```
add_action('um_user_edit_profile', 'um_post_edit_pending_hook', 10, 2); 
function um_post_edit_pending_hook($user_id, $args){ 
    if ( current_user_can('administrator') ) {
        return false;
    } else { 
        global $ultimatemember; 
        $ultimatemember->user->pending(); 
    }
}
```

> [***P.S.*** *here is a related question, gmazzap's answer has more detail*](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/131816/87531).

Comment: I needed 2 things: to know if is admin should work and if the hook was formatted OK.  From your posts I got this info.  There are all sorts of different access rights for users with this plug-in, so I was struggling to find something this user could do different to admin.  Through the link @user45250 posted I discovered ‘if ( is_super_admin’ and that worked fine. I’m grateful.  Consensus seems to accept user45250 as the answerer, so I will credit them.

Comment: Why don’t the people down voting this post be constructive and leave reasons why. The post seems reasonable to me; I spent a long time on the problem, I did lots of research and tried lots of different alternatives.   Isn't this why the forum exists. I know people at uni that won't come here for help anymore because of all the down voting and editing of comments for no reason. Suggested improvement is let me down vote the down voters. Rant over.